# Hadoop NameNode Ip Address

Tags: hadoop, namenode

I'm using ***Hadoop MapReduce*** paradigm, and i need to get the ***NameNode*** **IP address** from the ***DataNode***, can any one give me an idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way would be to quickly open the **core-site.xml** file under **HADOOP_HOME/conf** directory. The value of **fs.default.name** property will tell you the host and port where NN is running.

Comment: The **fs.default.name** gives the Localhost of the DataNode Tarek.we can use this only in the namenode.

Comment: That means you are running in pseudo distributed mode(All processes on a single machine). In this case the NN machine is same as the DN machine.

Comment: No i used it on a multicluster hadoop, and when i try to get the IP addresse from the DataNode it gives me 127.0.0.1/localhost

Comment: Could you please show me your **configuration files**, along with the **slaves** file present inside HADOOP_HOME/conf directory?

Comment: <name>fs.default.name</name>

<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>

Comment: slaves 
localhost
slave
slave2
slave3
slave4

Comment: Although your slaves file contains multiple hostnames, I doubt if it is actually a fully distributed setup. Could you please point your web browser to the NN webUI(NN_machine:50070) and make sure of this?

Comment: localhost:50070 and the datanode

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line 127.0.0.1 localhost in your /etc/host and put your IP and the name of all your machines. Hadoop is resolving all the IPs and names of machines on the cluster as 127.0.0.1 localhost if you leave the file as default.

Comment: this seems logique, i'll do that and give you the results.
Regards.

Comment: no error, the question was how to get the IP address of the namenode, and your solution still gives me the localhost address.

Comment: I don't really understand ... It's you who define the ip adress of your machine ... no ?

Comment: the problem is that i don't know if IP in a hadoop cluster, are static or DHCP?

Comment: if they are static then the problem is resolved, otherwise i still have much work to do .

Comment: You should go for static ip because Hadoop is very sensitive on ip.

Comment: and for big hadoop clusters are they static or dynamic IPs ??

Comment: I don't know but trust me, it's very  simpler in static IP ^^